# Splitting element class into two classes html.slim in ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

noobie here:
I have authentication method icons that I want to style separately, however they falls under the same class and I do not understand how to rewrite it to use two different for fb and google.

HTML SLIM code:

```
- if devise_mapping.omniauthable?
  .row
    .col-sm-12
      p.text-center.small-link= t('html.text.or_oauth_login')
      .col-sm-12.d-flex.justify-content-center.oauth-box
        - resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider|
          a.tooltiptext.left[style="position:absolute; left: -10px; top: 43px; color: #FFFFFF;"]= t('html.links.tooltiptext')
          = link_to image_tag("#{provider}_logo.png", size: "40x40"), omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "oauth-icon"
```

So the only class is "oauth-icon" . And I assume it takes #{provider} from devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "xxxxxxxx", 
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx" {}
```

How should it be rewritten to have two classes?

Answer (score 0):

You could add another class that is created dynamically like: `class: "oauth-icon #{provider}-icon"`, which would leave the `oauth-icon` class in place (I'm assuming it's needed), and then adds a `facebook-icon` class or `google_oauth2-icon` class, depending on the provider.